# CameraUpdate Factory won't zoom in on google maps (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
if(myLocation != null) 
{
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
    double langitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
    LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(latitude, langitude);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLocation));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));          
}
```

Is there a reason the two last lines aren't doing anything? The whole map of Africa just displays when I run the program (with the current location).

Comment: are you sure that those two lines are hit? (debug/log) are you sure you call them after the map is ready?

Comment: [Answer from stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723017/android-google-map-move-camera-from-position-to-another) this may help

Comment: I managed to make it work, although I'm not sure why by changing it to:                   mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocation, zoomLevel));